# SQL substr function

Tags: sql, oracle

in my table one column contains data as below
BMS/430301420-XN/0

I need to use substr function in oracle and output to be taken as

```
430301420-XN
```

the one I used is as below

```
substr(buy_id,5),substr(substr(buy_id,5),instr(buy_id,'/',2))
```

but it is not working please help me

Comment: what is the result? error or wrong result?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the format of the string and you always want to start on the fifth character and remove the last two, then:

```
select substr(str, 5, -2)
```

If you just want the part between the slashes, then use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(str, '/.*/'), '/', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is a Regular Expression, find the string between the slashes but don't include them in the result:

```
regexp_substr(buy_id, '(?<=/).*(?=/)')
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'BMS/430301420-XN/0' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'BMSABC/430301420-XN/0' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'BMS/430301420-XN/012345' str FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT str,
  7    SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '/', 1, 1)+1, instr(str, '/', 1, 2)
  8               -instr(str, '/', 1, 1)-1) new_str
  9  FROM DATA;

STR                     NEW_STR
----------------------- -----------------------
BMS/430301420-XN/0      430301420-XN
BMSABC/430301420-XN/0   430301420-XN
BMS/430301420-XN/012345 430301420-XN

SQL>
```

The above uses the logic to find the substring between the first and second **occurrence** of the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This will also Work :D

```
select Column_Name as OLD , substr(''||to_char(Column_Name)||'',instr
(''||to_char(Column_Name)||'','/',1)+1,(instr(''||to_char(Column_Name)
||'','/',1,2)-instr(''||to_char(Column_Name)||'','/',1,1)-1)) as NEW from Table_Name;
```

Same Use Of `substr` and `instr`

Answer (score 0):

### my answer is :

```
select 
substr('BMS/430301420-XN/0',
      (instr('BMS/430301420-XN/0','/') +1),
      (instr('BMS/430301420-XN/0','/',(instr('BMS/430301420-XN/0','/')+1))-instr('BMS/430301420-XN/0','/')-1 ))
from dual
```

### you can see this sample :

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/863/0